# Control div height using Bulma CSS column

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, bulma

In order to have a responsive page, I use Bulma CSS column (based on CSS flexbox) which:

- Split my page on two equals width columns on desktop.
- Stack the two full width columns on mobile.

On the left column, I except to display a static map widget, using the screen full-height.

On the right column, I want to vertically split in two rows:

- The top row (in blue), containing few controls and having a dynamic height based on content.
- The bottom row (in red), containing table of data and having a dynamic height based on remaining space inside the screen.

The overall picture is to have a desktop webpage contained in the screen dimension.

My issue regards the bottom row height:

- If I set a fixed height using percentage, the row height is not optimal depending on the screen (a small unused space could remains underneath).
- if I do not set a fixed height, the row overflows from the screen (instead of adding a scroll bar inside the row).

Also I want to avoid, as much as possible, customisation, and maybe I could use some Bulma out-the-box layout: hero, tiles, ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" class="container is-fluid" style="height: 100vh;">
      <div class="columns" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="column" style="background-color: green;">
          <!-- Fixed full height zone -->
          <div id="map" style="height: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <!-- Dynamic height zone depending on centent -->
          <div class="container" style="background-color: blue;">
            <p class="buttons is-right">
              <button class="button">Button1</button>
              <button class="button">Button2</button>
            </p>      
          </div>
          <!-- Dynamic height zone depending on remaining space inside the screen -->
          <div class="table-container" style="overflow-y:scroll;" style="background-color: red;">
            <table class="table is-fullwidth">
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
              <tr><td>bla</td></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```